# Inequality of the norm of the convolution in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with symmetric decreasing rearrangement?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, inequalities, calculus-of-variations

Is it true that
$$
||f*g||_p \le ||\,|f|^* * |g|^*||_p\quad ?
$$
where $|f|^*$ and $|g|^*$ are the symmetric decreasing rearrangements of the functions $|f|$ and $|g|$. Under what conditions on $f$ and $g$ this is true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this follows from the [Riesz rearrangement inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_rearrangement_inequality):
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} h(x)(f*g)(x)\, dx \le \int_{\mathbb R^n} h^*(x) (f^* *g^*)(x)\, dx
$$
(We can assume that all functions are $\ge 0$.) Since $\|h^*\|_q=\|h\|_q$, this shows that
$$
\|f*g\|_p = \sup_{\|h\|_q=1} \int |h(f*g)| \le \|f^* *g^*\|_p ,
$$
as desired (with $1/p+1/q=1$).